# Disabling Back button of Browser on Logout click like Yahoo,Gmail etc for Security

Tags: c#, asp.net

First, I am setting the session variable as Session["SessionId"] in the globle.asax file as below:-

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  // Code that runs when a new session is started
  string sessionId = Session.SessionID;
  Session["SessionId"] = "true";
}
```

I am using this code in the page_load() event of master page:-

```
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
Response.Expires = -1500;
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";

if(Session["SessionId"] == null)
{
  Response.Redirect("PatientLoginPage.aspx");
}
```

and using Firefox as my default brower, but it is not working in it as well as Chrome broweser correct me if i am wrong please help me...

Thanks in advance,

vaibhav D.

Answer (score 3):

If i'm not mistaken, Gmail and Yahoo use 2 redirects when logging out, so when you click "back" you actually go back to a bogus page, not the one before you logged out.
Try to to the same.

Also the type of redirect used might affect the browser history or not (i'm reffering here to redirect from the http headers or a redirect from a simple javascript).

Try to experiment a littpe with this info and a bogus "proxy" page, that acts as an intermediate between the mode "loggen in" and the "logged out" mode

Comment: can u be more specific?
Please tell me what mistake in my code?

Comment: @Vaibhavd: Basically, when your application logs a user out, you should redirect the user to (for example) loggedout.aspx - that page then does nothing more than redirect them to a page informing them they are logged out, or the login page, the homepage whatever. That way, if the user clicks on the back button, they go to loggedout.aspx, which immediately bounces them to the same page again.

Comment: But if user click more than 2 times thy can navigate through the whole pages?

Comment: can you tell me the mistake in my code the pages that the browser is taking from browser catch,so page is not reload it just invoke form the catch,i cleared the catch from using the same code it works fine in IE but not in the Firefox, I want to code on the browsers back button so that after clicking it pop massage appires saying your session has expired and will rediret to the same page(login page)

Comment: You cannot disable the back button, that's why you have to use 2 pages and the "no-cache" directives. Are you sure that the browser receives the correct headers and doesn't cache the page from where the "logout" button was pressed?

Answer (score 1):

Session_Start will be called each time a session is started - so even if you're calling Session.Abandon() in your logout code, as soon as the user hits a new page, Session_Start will be fired (as it looks like a new session), and Session["SessionId"] will no longer be null, and will be set back to "true" again.

I think [Misquamaqus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286932/disabling-back-button-of-browser-on-logout-click-like-yahoo-gmail-etc-for-securit/1286962#1286962) has the right answer about how to go about "disabling" the back button, but this should help resolve the issue in your master page..

Comment: can you tell me the mistake in my code the pages that the browser is taking from browser catch,so page is not reload it just invoke form the catch,i cleared the catch from using the same code it works fine in IE but not in the Firefox, I want to code on the browsers back button so that after clicking it pop massage appires saying your session has expired and will rediret to the same page(login page)