# stop back behaviour in android phone in web browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-browser

I have read this link

[How can we stop web page view after sign-out using browser back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476398/how-can-we-stop-web-page-view-after-signout-using-browser-back)

My problem is bit different

I have one webpage, in which viewing of div is controlled by JS

Now say initially I am on **div1**, once I click on change div icon, **div2** appears and **div1** is disappeared, now if someone presses back button on android it goes on previous page and i wanted to display **div1** hiding **div2**.

any help??

Comment: Include your possible code for the reference.

Comment: Paresh its the simple HTML code, nothin special

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved used onhashchange(), it helped.

Answer (score 0):

possible solution, whenever div2 appear create one method that sets a flag for div2, and call through JS. `onBackPressed()` method just check that flag value is set or not, if yes then create another function that call JS function to disappear div2 and make div1 visible. And don't forget to reset the flag value..  This is just an idea as you don't have shared your code..

Comment: **onBackPressed()** can be used in javascript?

Comment: no it's only for Activity, as JS is not able to listen key events.. you need to create a method that call your JS method..

Comment: in that case on which event should i bind my function?

Comment: just one again gone through my ans.. you'll find the flow.. I can't explain more then that..

Comment: Yuvi thanks for your help, but there is nothing related to the android OS, i have got just HTML page and android browser thats it..

Comment: so haven't write JavaScript for that page.. That's why you are not getting.. By the way you can use JS function to call your Activity Methods and vice-versa. I'll suggest you to go through some Android webpage & JS tutorials.. That will clear your concepts...