# Prevent users from accessing member pages by entering cached url

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a website where members have to login but I noticed after logging out they can simply enter any page url in browser and go back in without using the login form, how do I prevent this.

What I mean is I believe there is a way for me to check if the session is valid on all pages. Even non users can put the url in their browsers and enter without logging in.

Comment: By logging them out/checking for a login properly? How are you currently handling these tasks? (Please update your question with the relevant code snippets.)

Comment: Use [**sessions**](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) and maybe [**tokens**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php). What are you using now, can you show what you have code-wise?

Comment: Invalidate the user cache on logout (vague question, vague answer)

Comment: Here is a page I recently found on using tokens in a form, it may be of use to you. [**Click here to read it.**](http://phpro.org/tutorials/Preventing-Multiple-Submits.html) It also uses sessions.

Comment: I made an edit please read and help, thanks. @middaparka

Comment: @user2636507 I for one can't help you without seeing some of your code. Maybe a PRO will be able to give you an answer without seeing a single "character", however I am pretty good and do "have my moments". Good luck, I wish you well. (*Peace*)

Comment: @user2636507 - you'll have to include code to check if the user is currently logged in on every page where you want to prevent access. If a just-logged-out user hits back, or if a non-user goes to the link, they'll fail the logged in check and you can handle it as required.

Comment: Can this help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476398/how-can-we-stop-web-page-view-after-signout-using-browser-back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the SESSION variable in PHP.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['login'] = true;
```

This basically creates a SESSION variable called 'login' which can be used to verify whether a user is logged in.
Now, all you have to do is check the variable like this :

```
if($_SESSION['login'] == true){
    /*GOTO USER PAGE*/
}else{
    /*REDIRECT SOMEWHERE ELSE */
}
```

To create a logout button, to ensure users can't copy-paste the URL again and enter,

```
session_destroy();
```

will work just fine.

Comment: how do i add a page for it to redirect if its not logged in -else{
    /*REDIRECT SOMEWHERE ELSE */- @KaniskaGanguly can I use header?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create a proper login system using something like a session. There are countless tutorials you'll find about this by googling "php login tutorial with session". [Here](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL) is one of those results.

At the heart of all of these are PHP Sessions, which allow you to store information for a specific client throughout their browser session. To understand sessions in php, here's a [basic tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Let me know if these make sense or if you have any questions :)

Comment: this was indeed useful